# How to query the newer version of SWAPI using REACT Graphql to get all people?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am having a bit of headache with Graphql, the tutorials I have seen online so far are not giving me the exact thing I require, even some article which requires exactly what I need is no longer working well with the new version on SWAPI or say at least querying it doesn't work as supposed to be. THE URI for this API is [Link to SWAPI](https://swapi.dev/api/). Queries I am trying to run are [get all people](https://swapi.dev/api/people/), being able to cater for [pagination](https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2) and lastly being able to search by [sending a name](https://swapi.dev/api/people/?search=Anakin%20Skywalker). These I can easily achieve with REST API, but I am having trouble getting them in GRAPHQL and REACT.

The only thing I managed to have it work is querying a specific person by the number

```
const PERSON = gql`
  query Person {
    person @rest(type: "Person", path: "/people/1/") {
      name
      height
      mass
      gender
      homeworld
    }
  }
`;

RESPONSE

{
   "person":{
      "__typename":"Person",
      "name":"Luke Skywalker",
      "height":"172",
      "mass":"77",
      "gender":"male",
      "homeworld":"https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/"
   }
}
```

Below is what I have tried so far to get all people:

```
const GET_PEOPLE = gql`
  query GetPeople {
    people @rest(type: "[Person]", path: "people/") {
      name
      height
    }
  }
`;
```

Which return:

```
{"people":{"__typename":"[Person]","name":null,"height":null}}
```

Answer (score 1):

in case someone still needs this, to get the persons you actually need to use the people type:

```
{
  allPeople( first: 10 ) {
      totalCount
      people {
          name
          height
      }
  }
}
```

Here's a [link](https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql/?query=%7B%20allPeople(%20first%3A10%20%20)%20%7B%0A%09totalCount%0A%20%20pageInfo%7B%0A%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20hasPreviousPage%0A%20%20%20%20startCursor%0A%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20edges%7B%0A%20%20%20%20cursor%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20people%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20filmConnection%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20films%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0A) to this request

Comment: "in case someone still needs this" 7 months later. it seems GraphQL is not a hot topic, yet it also seems many companies use it